# Use sessions to count pageviews django detailview

Tags: django, python-3.x, detailview, pageviews

I am trying to count the visits to a view. I would like for the counter to increment by 1 every time someone calls up the view. Then, I want the "visits" field on the model to automatically update with the latest count. However, I am not sure how to implement this. Using some code I've found, I am trying this:

models.py

```
class Statute(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,
                                null = True)
    statute_name = models.CharField(max_length=25,
                                    default='')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=55,
                                default='')
    section_number = models.CharField(max_length=55,
                                    default='')
    section_title = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                        default='')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField(default='')

    slug = models.SlugField()
```

views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LibraryInStateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        state = State.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('state'))
        statute = Statute.objects.all()
        context['latest_statutes'] = statute.filter(
                address__zipcode__city__county__state=state).order_by(
                '-timestamp')
        context['statute_count'] = Statute.objects.filter(
                address__zipcode__city__county__state=state).count()    
        context['view_count'] = self.request.session['visits']+1
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include it in `.get_object()` method in `LibraryInStateView`

```
def get_object(self):
    statute = super().get_object()
    statute.visits += 1
    statute.save()

    self.view_count = statute.visits
    return statute
```

Or get method:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    statute = # ... code to retrieve Statute for this view
    statute.visits += 1
    statute.save()

    self.view_count = statute.visits
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then once you attached `view_count` to class instance, you can add it to context:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        context['view_count'] = self.view_count
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view update:

```
statute = Statute.objects.filter(address__zipcode__city__county__state=state)
statute.visits += 1
statute.save()
context['statute_count'] = statute
```

Comment: Doesn't that just increment the statute number? I am trying to increment the number of visits to a page generated by the DetailView.

Comment: Also, this example will raise an error - `statute` variable here contains a queryset, not an object. You cannot attach an attribute to it.